# Xamarin Android Calendar Events

Tags: android, calendar, xamarin

I'm trying to implement calendar events in my app, and I was following example from xamarin site and their calander demo but it's not working. I can launch application and when I press button to add event nothing happens.Here is my code does anyone knows why it's not working.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Provider;
using Java.Util;

namespace Bingo
{
    [Activity(Label = "EventListActivity")]
     public class EventListActivity : ListActivity
  {
    int _calId;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.EventList);

        _calId = Intent.GetIntExtra ("calId", -1); 

        ListEvents ();

        InitAddEvent ();
    }

    void ListEvents ()
    {       
        var eventsUri = CalendarContract.Events.ContentUri;

        string[] eventsProjection = { 
            CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Id,
            CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Title,
            CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtstart
        };

        var cursor = ManagedQuery (eventsUri, eventsProjection, 
            String.Format ("calendar_id={0}", _calId), null, "dtstart ASC");

        string[] sourceColumns = {
            CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Title, 
            CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtstart
        };

        int[] targetResources = { Resource.Id.eventTitle, Resource.Id.eventStartDate };

        var adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter (this, Resource.Layout.EventListItem, 
            cursor, sourceColumns, targetResources); 

        adapter.ViewBinder = new ViewBinder ();

        ListAdapter = adapter;

        ListView.ItemClick += (sender, e) => { 
            int i = (e as AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs).Position;

            cursor.MoveToPosition(i);
            int eventId = cursor.GetInt (cursor.GetColumnIndex (eventsProjection [0]));
            var uri = ContentUris.WithAppendedId(CalendarContract.Events.ContentUri, eventId);
            var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, uri);
            StartActivity(intent);              
        };
    }

    void InitAddEvent ()
    {
        var addSampleEvent = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.addSampleEvent);

        addSampleEvent.Click += (sender, e) => {           
            // Create Event code
            ContentValues eventValues = new ContentValues ();
            eventValues.Put (CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.CalendarId, _calId);
            eventValues.Put (CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Title, "Test Event from M4A");
            eventValues.Put (CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Description, "This is an event created from Mono for Android");
            eventValues.Put (CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtstart, GetDateTimeMS (2015, 12, 15, 10, 0));
            eventValues.Put (CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtend, GetDateTimeMS (2015, 12, 15, 11, 0));


            eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventTimezone, "UTC");
            eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventEndTimezone, "UTC");

            var uri = ContentResolver.Insert (CalendarContract.Events.ContentUri, eventValues);
            Console.WriteLine ("Uri for new event: {0}", uri);
        };
    }

    class ViewBinder : Java.Lang.Object, SimpleCursorAdapter.IViewBinder
    {     
        public bool SetViewValue (View view, Android.Database.ICursor cursor, int columnIndex)
        {
            if (columnIndex == 2) {
                long ms = cursor.GetLong (columnIndex);

                DateTime date = 
                    new DateTime (1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddMilliseconds (ms).ToLocalTime ();

                TextView textView = (TextView)view;
                textView.Text = date.ToLongDateString ();

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }     
    }

    long GetDateTimeMS (int yr, int month, int day, int hr, int min)
    {
        Calendar c = Calendar.GetInstance (Java.Util.TimeZone.Default);

        c.Set (Java.Util.CalendarField.DayOfMonth, 15);
        c.Set (Java.Util.CalendarField.HourOfDay, hr);
        c.Set (Java.Util.CalendarField.Minute, min);
        c.Set (Java.Util.CalendarField.Month, Calendar.December);
        c.Set (Java.Util.CalendarField.Year, 2015);

        return c.TimeInMillis;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the READ_CALENDAR permission set in the Android Manifest. Described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a late entry but I just went through this on my xamarin forms app and had to cobble tips and guesses from all over to do what seems like a simple task.  My example is slightly different as I'm doing a dependency service but I think it should help the next guy.

This should pop the create event panel for your user and let them tweak the title and stuff before they hit save.  Also you shouldn't need the read/write calendar permissions in your manifest for this since we're writing from the calendar app.

Also this works in my emulator. API 24

```
 [assembly: Dependency(typeof(CalendarAppointmentService))]
namespace Foo.Droid.Services
{
    [Activity(Label = "CalendarAppointment")]
    public class CalendarAppointmentService : ICalendarAppointmentService
    {
        private readonly static DateTime referenceDate = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        public CalendarAppointmentService()
        {

        }

        public async Task<bool> AddAppointment(AddAppointmentModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                Intent eventValues = new Intent(Intent.ActionInsert);
                eventValues.SetData(CalendarContract.Events.ContentUri);
                eventValues.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                eventValues.PutExtra(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Title, model.Title);
                eventValues.PutExtra(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Description, model.Description);
                eventValues.PutExtra(CalendarContract.ExtraEventBeginTime, GetDateAsAndroidMS(model.StartDateTimeUTC));
                eventValues.PutExtra(CalendarContract.ExtraEventEndTime, GetDateAsAndroidMS(model.EndDateTimeUTC));
                eventValues.PutExtra(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventTimezone, "UTC");
                eventValues.PutExtra(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventEndTimezone, "UTC");
                eventValues.PutExtra(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventLocation, model.Location);
                Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(eventValues);

                return await Task.FromResult(true);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {   }
            return await Task.FromResult(false);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts a System.DateTime to an Android-expected long of milliseconds since 1970.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The date as Android long value.</returns>
        /// <param name="date">Source DateTime.</param>
        public static long GetDateAsAndroidMS(DateTime date)
        {
            return (long)(date.ToUniversalTime() - referenceDate).TotalMilliseconds;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem but I resolved it, first check in manifest file for required permissions. Then, don't use your emulator to sync with the calendar, use an actual mobile device and then try syncing and it'll work perfectly.